# How to install fonts for X?

Tags: linux, xorg, fonts, unicode

I would like to setup a Linux system with ScrotWM as the window manager, but I noticed that X is aware of only a few fonts. I would like to have UTF-8 fonts that support multiple languages, including Asian languages like Japanese and Traditional Chinese.
How do I install fonts so that X can show them? What kind of fonts would they be? And will the fonts be universally available to other programs like Firefox or OpenOffice once I install them? Or will applications maintain separate groups of fonts for their own use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step-by-step manual how to install to Linux the multiple fonts from the specific folder:

1. Open the `Terminal` application and gain root privileges by typing `su` and the correct root password.
2. Go to the folder with the fonts by using `cd` command, e.g suppose, the user font folder is in Downloads:

   ```
   cd /home/**user_name**/Downloads/Fonts
   ```
3. Copy the font files to the system-wide fonts directory `/usr/share/font`:

   ```
   find . -iname '*.ttf' -exec ln -srvf {} /usr/share/fonts/ \;
   ```
4. Refresh the system font cache with `fc-cache`, e.g.:

   ```
   fc-cache -v
   ```

Answer (score 6):

To add fonts while X server is running use command:

```
xset fp+ /path/to/dir/with/fonts/
```

And, if needed:

```
xset fp rehash
```

To make this permanent add `FontPath` line to your xorg.conf

Answer (score 4):

You can download fonts (i.e TTF files) then put them in `~/.fonts` (for personal use) or `/usr/share/fonts` (for everyone). After that X should pick up the font list and make it available to all applications (you may have to log out and log back in first).